# Combining values of a same category

Tags: r

I have a table like this:

```
Values        Type       Year
1500          A          1
964           B          1
-222          B          2
761           A          2
2400          C          1
-100          A          1
144           B          2
```

My question is: how can I show the positive and negative values separately (creating 2 data frames named POsitive value and Negative value, in my opinion) and how to demonstrate netted values?

The expected output 1 is:

```
Data frame 1 (positive values):
Values        Type       Year
1500          A          1 
964           B          1
761           A          2
2400          C          1
144           B          2


Data frame 2 (negative values):
Values        Type       Year
-222          B          2
-100          A          1
```

Expected output 2 (netted values):

```
Values         Type      Year
1400           A         1
761            A         2
964            B         1
-78            B         2
2400           C         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` for the first problem, and `aggregate` for the second:

```
split(d, ifelse(d$Values > 0, "POSITIVE", "NEGATIVE")) 

$NEGATIVE
  Values Type Year
3   -222    B    2
6   -100    A    1

$POSITIVE
  Values Type Year
1   1500    A    1
2    964    B    1
4    761    A    2
5   2400    C    1
7    144    B    2

aggregate(Values ~ Year + Type, data = d, FUN = sum)

  Year Type Values
1    1    A   1400
2    2    A    761
3    1    B    964
4    2    B    -78
5    1    C   2400
```

#### Data

```
d <- structure(list(Values = c(1500L, 964L, -222L, 761L, 2400L, -100L, 144L), 
                    Type = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "A", "B"), 
                    Year = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), 
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy using `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
df <- read.table( text  = "Values        Type       Year
1500          A          1
964           B          1
-222          B          2
761           A          2
2400          C          1
-100          A          1
144           B          2", header = T)

dt <- as.data.table(df)

# negative table
ndt <- dt[Values < 0]

# positive table
pdt <- dt[Values > 0]

# netted table
dt[, list(Values = sum(Values)), by = c("Type", "Year")]
```

```
> ndt
   Values Type Year
1:   -222    B    2
2:   -100    A    1

> pdt <- dt[Values > 0]

> pdt
   Values Type Year
1:   1500    A    1
2:    964    B    1
3:    761    A    2
4:   2400    C    1
5:    144    B    2

> edt <- dt[, list(Values = sum(Values)), by = c("Type", "Year")]

> edt
   Type Year Values
1:    A    1   1400
2:    B    1    964
3:    B    2    -78
4:    A    2    761
5:    C    1   2400
```